# library not found for -lippicv

Tags: opencv, g++

After installing opencv3  on my OSX,I run this command

```
 g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` facedetect.cpp -o /tmp/test && /tmp/test
```

I got this error

```
  ld: library not found for -lippicv
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling with Mac OSX, I ran into the same problem and found a solution [here](http://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-on-yosemite-osx-10-10-x/), under "Install OpenCV 3 on Mac OSX with brew", "Troubleshooting":

```
# Find ippicv 
find /usr/local -name "libippicv.a"
# For me it is /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a

# Make a symlink to /usr/local/lib 
ln -s /some/path/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a /usr/local/lib/

# I used
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.1.0_3/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libippicv.a /usr/local/lib/
```